# ASP.NET Core, overkilling Task.Run()?

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core, blocking

Lets say we have an ASP.NET Core receiving a string as a payload, size order of couple of megabytes. First method implementation:

```
[HttpPost("updateinfos")]
public async Task UpdateInfos()
{
    var len = (int)this.Request.ContentLength;
    byte[] b = new byte[len];
    await this.Request.Body.ReadAsync(b,0,len);
    var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
    .....
}
```

Body is read with `ReadAsync`, this is good since we have I/O stuff on socket and having it asynchronous is for free due to the nature of the call itself. But if we have a look after, the `GetString()` method, is purely CPU, is blocking with linear complexity. Anyway this affect somehow the performance since other clients wait for my bytes to get converted in string. I think to avoid this the solution is to run  `GetString()` on the thread pool, by this:

```
[HttpPost("updateinfos")]
public async Task UpdateInfos()
{
    var len = (int)this.Request.ContentLength;
    byte[] b = new byte[len];
    await this.Request.Body.ReadAsync(b,0,len);
    var content = await Task.Run(()=>ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(b));
    .....
}
```

please don't mind the return right now, something more has to be done in the function.

So the question, is the second approach overkilling? If so, what is the boundary to discriminate what could be run as blocking and what has to be moved to another thread?

Comment: I believe the 2nd is not needed because each http request should already be on it's own thread, but there may be something here I'm missing (hence just a comment). Alternatively, you could wrap up all of that in one `await` lambda.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` at all? Either way, the method cannot return until the task has completed, since you're awaiting it. Then, you're allowing the active thread to *potentially* be returned to the pool, but you're taking a new one from the *same* pool to run the task. As a result, all you're doing here is just adding unnecessary thread-switching.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn well in ASP.NET core model is different from standard asp.net, if controller method is async, does not run on a separate thread.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I removed the last Tark.Run cause is misleading, just focalize on the GetString()

Comment: Then, the same advice applies even more clearly. `Task.Run` isn't magic that makes sync stuff async. It's still sync and still going to tie up a thread. All you're doing with `Task.Run` is trading one thread for another, which is actually *less* efficient, when it could all be run on the same thread.

Comment: @ChrisPratt less efficient, but not blocking, isn't?

Comment: Additionally, streaming the request body manually here isn't buying you anything. The only reason to stream is if you're passing that into some process that can work on a stream. Since you're awaiting reading all the bytes, this still halts your code until the entire request body is in - no different than if you had simply taken it as a param.

Comment: No. Still blocking. Again, you're awaiting the task, so your code stops right there until it completes. The only difference is that in scenario 1 you're running on the same thread, whereas in scenario two, you've switched threads. However, both threads came from the same pool, so returning one and pulling out another buys you nothing, and either way a thread is blocked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179396/discussion-between-felice-pollano-and-chris-pratt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very much abusing `Task.Run` there. `Task.Run` is used to off-load work onto a different thread and asynchronously wait for it to complete. So every `Task.Run` call will cause thread context switches. Of course, that is usually a very bad idea to do for things that should not run on their own thread.

Things like `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(b)` are **really fast**. The overhead involved in creating and managing a thread that encapsulates this is much larger than just executing this directly on the same thread.

You should generally use `Task.Run` only to off-load (primarily synchronous) work that can benefit from running on its own thread. Or in cases, where you have work that would take a bit longer but block the current execution.

In your example, that is simply not the case, so you should just call those methods synchronously.

---

If you really want to reduce the work for that code, you should look at how to work properly streams. What you do in your code is read the request body stream completely and only then you work on it (trying to translate into a string).

Instead of separating the process of reading the binary stream and then translating it into a string, you could just read the stream as a string directly using a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader). That way, you can read the request body directly, even asynchronously. So depending on what you actually do with it afterwards, that may be a lot more efficient.

Comment: This is good, I guess it was overkillig, don't mind about last Task, removed from the sample, just rubbish

Comment: It's not spawning a new thread. This is not an accurate statement.

Comment: @poke did'nt notice StreamReader has the ReadStringAsync, I'm an old .NET boy  ;)

Comment: @christopherclark: What do you mean? If you're saying `Task.Run` doesn't pull a thread, you're incorrect. It very much does. That's how it works.

Comment: I think christopher is hinting at that `Task.Run` will schedule things on the thread pool, so this will enable thread *reuse*. So a *new* thread isn’t spawned all the time. I adjusted the wording a bit to match that. But overall, the effect is still the same.

Comment: @ChrisPratt what poke said. And it very much depends on the use case if this is abuse or not. I think you guys are applying the old dotnet mentality of thread creation, when in core/linux its extremely cheap. We can't know his use case. He has `...` after the `Task.Run` method. He could be doing many other things that might benefit awaiting the cpu bound work, or multiple tasks, and waiting all before returning to the client. The client might only need a 202 Accepted message, so just let this all run in the background anyways.

Comment: It's not "running in the background" if it's being awaited. And, using `Task.Run` in a web context pretty much never makes sense, because you're just trading one thread for another out of the same limited pool. It doesn't really matter what exactly the OP is doing, ultimately, this still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ChrisPratt False. I probably didn't explain myself well, but If I created 5 tasks, And at the end waited for all tasks because they had no relation to each other. It will be an improvement almost guaranteed. And it is running in the background in the context of returning a 202. If I want to sign up for notifications on stack overflow. I don't need the server to set me up, put things in a database, update caches, send events, and THEN return to me. All I need is a 202 returned to the client, and all that work will "run in the background"

Comment: @christopherclark OP’s example sounds very much *not* like that though. This example was in particular decoding the request body to a string, likely to do something with it afterwards. I agree that there are use cases to off-loading stuff into separate threads, but this very likely isn’t one of those.

Comment: @christopherclark: I have no idea what you're talking about. Yes, you can offload the task and return a 202 Accepted and call it a day, but that's not what the OP is doing here. The `await` keyword is going to halt the code until the delegate being passed to `Task.Run` returns (because there's a return value and not void, it will trigger the generic overload here). In other words, by the time you can actually return that 202, all the work is done anyways. If the OP chose to *not* await, then yes the code could continue running, but then you loose access to the actual return which is needed.